# Order of integration change $\int_0^\infty \int_0^{x/\sqrt{t}}e^{-y^2/2}\,dy\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

If we have the double integral

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \int_0^{x/\sqrt{t}}\exp\bigg (-\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg)dydt$, where $x > 0$

We get inequalities:

$0 \le t < \infty$ and $0 \le y \le \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}} \implies 0 \le t < \infty $ and $0 \le t \le \frac{x^2}{y^2}$

The inner integral will then be $\int_0^{x^2/y^2}\exp(-y^2/2)dt$.

The answer to the change will be:

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \int_0^{x/\sqrt{t}}\exp\bigg (-\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg)dydt = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{x^2/y^2}\exp\bigg (-\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg)dtdy $

My question is why does the limit of integration for $y$ become $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: The double integral is over the area bounded by the $t$-axis, the $y$-axis and the curve $y^2 t=x^2$ ($x$ is a constant). Sketch it and you'll have an answer to your question.

Comment: @metamorphy OP has it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the comment by @ancientmathematician :

WLOG let $x = 1$ as $x > 0$. Using the bounding curves $t$-axis, $y-$axis and $ty^2 = x^2$. And conditions $0 \le t < \infty, 0 \le y \le \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}$

To get the limits of integration for $y$, let $t$ be fixed. Then

$y^2=\frac{1}{t}$ and letting $t \to \infty$ we get $y^2 \to 0$ and letting $t \to 0$ we get $y^2 \to \infty$

And we know $y \ge 0$ from the conditions above thus $0 \le y < \infty$ in the change-of-order.